# Specify a bijective function $f:[0,1] \longrightarrow [0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

**Specify a bijective function $f:[0,1] \longrightarrow [0,1)$**

I know that such a function can't be continuous, so I've tried to find a function with one or more discontinuities, but with no progress so far.

Comment: I am sure I have seen this question on this site before, but in the meantime. Consider the sets $A=\{1,1/2,1/3,\dots\}$ and $B=\{1/2,1/3,1/4,\dots\}$ can you find a bijection between them? Can you then extend this bijection to have domain $[0,1]$ and range $[0,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that it's fairly east to find a bijection between two countable infinite set.
Now simply choose any countable infinite subset of $[0,1)$, put the extra end $1$ to $A$ to get a new set $B$, and you can have a bijective map from $A$ to $B$. Keep other elements unchanged and you just found a bijection form $[0,1)$ to $[0,1]$.